# Some questions about the choice of the definition of characteristic classes.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

In the following link : http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2017/REUPapers/Malaney.pdf , page : $13$ , there is a paragraph, which says :

> When looking at complex characteristic classes with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, there exist analogues of Stiefel-Whitney classes called Chern classes.  Once again we will skip the construction, but they can be defined axiomatically as follows :
>
> - **Definition $7.5.$** There exist characteristic classes $c_i$ of degree $2i$, for all $i > 0$ which are
>
> characterized by the following axioms :
>
> $ 1) $ $c_0 ( \xi ) = 1 $ for any vector bundle $\xi$.
>
> $ 2) $ If $\xi$ is an $n$ -dimentional vector bundle, then : $c_i (\xi ) = 0$ for $i > n$.
>
> $ 3) $ $  c_k ( \xi \oplus \nu ) = \displaystyle \sum_{ i = 0}^{k} c_i ( \xi ) \smallsmile c_{k-i} ( \nu ) $
>
> $ 4) $ For the canonical line bundle $ \gamma_{ \mathbb{C} }^n $ over $ BU(1) $ , $ c_1 ( \gamma_{ \mathbb{C} }^n ) $ is a fixed generator of $ H^2 ( BU(1) )$. We could also require that $c_1 ( \gamma_{ \mathbb{C} }^n ) $ be  the  Euler  class  of  the underlying $2$-dimensional  real  vector  bundle. We  will  define  the  Euler class later in this section.

- I would like to ask you about the third point of the definition above :

> $ 3) $ $  c_k ( \xi \oplus \nu ) = \displaystyle \sum_{ i = 0}^{k} c_i ( \xi ) \smallsmile c_{k-i} ( \nu ) $

Why do we put this condition 3) in this definition ? In other words, why do we want that the Chern classes check this condition 3) ? What is its origin ? From where does it come ?

- Another question that i hope to understand :

How  do we find or construct explicitly the Chern classes : $ c_k $ for $ k=0,1, ... , n $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The proof that these axioms determine Chern classes goes roughly as follows: first we know by (1), (2), and (4) what they are for the tautological line bundle, and so by naturality for all line bundles.  The splitting principle allows us to reduce the calculation for higher rank bundles to sums of line bundles, which (3) tells us how to compute.   So (3) is essential!

Comment: Condition 3) is really natural: if you think of two polynomials $f =\sum a_n x^n$ and $g =\sum b_m x^m$, then $fg$ is a polynomial whose $k$th coefficient is $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i b_{k-i}$.

Comment: Sorry @JHF, it's hard to understand what you say without a detail proof using mathematical language and formulas. Can you please, write me a detail proof for this fact if you have some free time ? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @Jason, what is $f$, and what is $g$ in this case ?

Comment: I think, i understand now. If : $ 0 \to \xi \to \xi \oplus \nu \to \nu \to 0 $ is exact, then : $ c(\xi \oplus \nu ) = c(\xi) \smallsmile c( \nu)$ . Thus, $ c_k = \sum c_i c_{k-i} $, right ?

Comment: What about the second question about the explicit construction of the Chern classes $ c_k $ pour $ k = 0 , 1 , \dots , n $ ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: @YoYo:  Exactly about your exact sequence of vector bundles.  There are many ways to construct the chern classes.  On method appears in Milnor and Stasheff's Characteristic classes book.

Comment: If you can read french Grothendieck wrote a very nice and short article about Chern classes where he explains everything :)